# How to improve sin/cos lut functions?

Tags: c, trigonometry

I am trying to optimize sin/cos for my MCU in order to calculate geo distance. This part of formula particularly is using trigonometry:

```
double e = (MyTan( lat2 / 2 + quarter_pi ) / MyTan( lat1 / 2 + quarter_pi ));
```

So I tried to build my own `sin/cos` lookup tables for `-PI` to `PI` as follows:

```
#define PARTPERDEGREE 10
double mysinlut[PARTPERDEGREE * 90 + 1];
double mycoslut[PARTPERDEGREE * 90 + 1];
void MySinCosCreate()
{
    int i;
    double angle, angleinc;

    // Each degree also divided into 10 parts
    angleinc = (M_PI / 180) / PARTPERDEGREE;
    for (i = 0, angle = 0.0; i <= (PARTPERDEGREE * 90 + 1); ++i, angle += angleinc)
    {
        mysinlut[i] = sin(angle);
    }

    angleinc = (M_PI / 180) / PARTPERDEGREE;
    for (i = 0, angle = 0.0; i <= (PARTPERDEGREE * 90 + 1); ++i, angle += angleinc)
    {
        mycoslut[i] = cos(angle);
    }
}



double MySin(double rad)
{
   int ix;
   int sign = 1;


   if(rad > (M_PI / 2))
        rad = M_PI / 2 - (rad - M_PI / 2);

   if(rad < -(M_PI / 2))
       rad = -M_PI / 2 - (rad + M_PI / 2);

   if(rad < 0)
   {
        sign = -1;
        rad *= -1;
   }

   ix = (rad * 180) / M_PI * PARTPERDEGREE;

   return sign * mysinlut[ix];
}

double MyCos(double rad)
{
   int ix;
   int sign = 1;


    if(rad > M_PI / 2)
    {
        rad = M_PI / 2 - (rad - M_PI / 2);
        sign = -1;
    }
    else if(rad < -(M_PI / 2))
    {
        rad = M_PI / 2 + (rad + M_PI / 2);
        sign = -1;
    }
    else if(rad > -M_PI / 2 && rad < M_PI / 2)
    {   
        rad = abs(rad);
        sign = 1;
    }

    ix = (rad * 180) / M_PI * PARTPERDEGREE;

    return sign * mycoslut[ix];
}

double MyTan(double rad)
{
    return MySin(rad) / MyCos(rad);
}
```

You can see the resolution of table is 10 parts per degree. I can increase it little, but it doesn't help much and it looks like I need some interpolation. Could anyone suggest some practical improvements to my functions to have better results? Below is graph of 234 different results of the `e`. Blue series are with ideal sin/cos and red are from LUT.

[image]

Comment: You could try approximating using the derivative `sin (x+h) ~ sin x + h*cos x`, that should give somewhat better results.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Do you mean when filling lookup table? Could you please answer with some tiny pseudocode even, which will give me hints on how to implement that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your lookup table is too coarse. If you can't make your table much finer, approximating the values using the derivative should get you a better result. We have

```
sin (x+h) ≈ sin x + h*cos x
cos (x+h) ≈ cos x - h*sin x
```

for small `h`. (You can get better approximations using higher derivatives or by using both values in the table between which your (computed) angle lies, but that would take longer, and I gather speed is the reason for the LUT in the first place.)

So after you normalised the angle, with

```
ix = (rad * 180) / M_PI * PARTPERDEGREE;
```

use

```
double h = rad - ix*angleinc;
return sign*(mysinlut[ix] + h*mycoslut[ix]);
```

resp.

```
return sign*(mycoslut[ix] - h*mysinlut[ix]);
```

That should not be too much slower, and ought to give significantly better approximations between the LUT points.

Comment: This makes LUT result even more than enough similar to ideal result! I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Actually there is a little problem when the result is switching sign... I will try to describe it shortly. I would appreciate if you could follow up and help me to resolve it.

Comment: Okay, I'll try. I have other things to do, too, though, so don't expect me to be very quick.

Comment: if you will have a chance, plz check my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765457/calculate-tan-having-sin-cos-lut

Answer (score 1):

An old but good recurrence relation for sin/cos interpolation described [here](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/math/inccos.html).

Comment: Is this something that I should apply on LUT, when loading value from table or this can replace completely LUT? I thought interpolation can be done using neighbor values in the table.