# Calculate tan having sin/cos LUT

Tags: c, optimization

```
#define PARTPERDEGREE 1
double mysinlut[PARTPERDEGREE * 90 + 1];
double mycoslut[PARTPERDEGREE * 90 + 1];
void MySinCosCreate()
{
    int i;
    double angle, angleinc;

    // Each degree also divided into 10 parts
    angleinc = (M_PI / 180) / PARTPERDEGREE;
    for (i = 0, angle = 0.0; i <= (PARTPERDEGREE * 90 + 1); ++i, angle += angleinc)
    {
        mysinlut[i] = sin(angle);
    }

    angleinc = (M_PI / 180) / PARTPERDEGREE;
    for (i = 0, angle = 0.0; i <= (PARTPERDEGREE * 90 + 1); ++i, angle += angleinc)
    {
        mycoslut[i] = cos(angle);
    }
}


double MySin(double rad)
{
    int ix;
    int sign = 1;
    double angleinc = (M_PI / 180) / PARTPERDEGREE;

    if(rad > (M_PI / 2))
        rad = M_PI / 2 - (rad - M_PI / 2);

    if(rad < -(M_PI / 2))
        rad = -M_PI / 2 - (rad + M_PI / 2);

    if(rad < 0)
    {
        sign = -1;
        rad *= -1;
    }

    ix = (rad * 180) / M_PI * PARTPERDEGREE;
    double h = rad - ix*angleinc;
    return sign*(mysinlut[ix] + h*mycoslut[ix]);
}

double MyCos(double rad)
{
    int ix;
    int sign = 1;
    double angleinc = (M_PI / 180) / PARTPERDEGREE;


    if(rad > M_PI / 2)
    {
        rad = M_PI / 2 - (rad - M_PI / 2);
        sign = -1;
    }
    else if(rad < -(M_PI / 2))
    {
        rad = M_PI / 2 + (rad + M_PI / 2);
        sign = -1;
    }
    else if(rad > -M_PI / 2 && rad < M_PI / 2)
    {   
        rad = abs(rad);
        sign = 1;
    }

    ix = (rad * 180) / M_PI * PARTPERDEGREE;

    double h = rad - ix*angleinc;
    return sign*(mycoslut[ix] - h*mysinlut[ix]);
}

double MyTan(double rad)
{
    return MySin(rad) / MyCos(rad);
}
```

It turns out that calculating `tan` using division is even more expensive than original `tan` function.

Is there any way to calculate `tan` using sin/cos lookup table values without division operation, since division is expensive on my MCU.

Is it better to have `tan` LUT and extract result using tan/sin or tan/cos as it's done now for sin/cos?

Comment: Division is expensive - why not just use another LUT for tan ? Also you could use just one LUT for sin/cos instead of two. And there's probably no point using doubles for these LUTs - float should be good enough if you're more interested in performance than accuracy.

Comment: @PaulR: First of all without approximating `sin (x+h) ≈ sin x + h*cos x` and `cos (x+h) ≈ cos x - h*sin x` the accuracy is not enough. Second of all I am not sure how to use `tan` to approximate it with sin or cos LUT. Need some practical help with that.

Comment: Still, if division is so slow, build a lookup table for `tan` (do you even need the `sin` and `cos` tables then?). You can then either approximate using the derivative, `tan (x+h) ≈ tan x + h*(1 + tan² x)` or linear interpolation, `double t = (rad * 180) / M_PI * PARTPERDEGREE; ix = (int)t; t -= ix; return t*mytanlut[ix+1] + (1-t)*mytanlut[ix];`. The linear interpolation would generally give better approximations, but has the problem that it would produce garbage if the two angles straddle `π/2` since one value would be very large and positive, the other very large and negative [possibly ±∞].

Comment: Some resources: http://www.myreckonings.com/Dead_Reckoning/Online/Materials/Fast_Approximation_of_Elementary_Functions.pdf and http://www.research.scea.com/research/pdfs/RGREENfastermath_GDC02.pdf

Comment: @DanielFischer: Let me try using both methods. Actually I need sin/cos tables anyway, because I use sin/cos elsewhere. As always, thanks!

Comment: @LiorKogan: I will check that, thanks

Comment: @DanielFischer: actually both methods gave pretty good result, except when approaching to `π/2` the error peak is very high. I've stopped on derivative method. Even after increasing resolution the error is less but still if it's possible to reduce that would solve the issue.

Comment: @Pablo why do you have *separate* LUTs for sin/cos? sin(x)==cos(PI/2-x)

Comment: @CAFxX: I thought it gives me extra precision when calculating `sin/cos` using derivative approximation? At least with one table I had not enough precision I remember.

Comment: @Pablo Yes, near `π/2` the derivative is huge and grows fast. You might get better results if you use the first terms of the Laurent expansion to approximate there. `tan x = cot (π/2 - x)`, and `cot y ≈ 1/y - y/3` for `y` close to 0. So `tan x ≈ 1/(π/2 - x) - (π/2 - x)/3` near `π/2`. (The second term is negligible very close to `π/2`.)

Comment: @Daniel Fischer So I should write condition and depending on input radian use different approximation mechanisms. Well, worth to try. Actually you could copy your comment as an answer so I could accept it, if you want. Meanwhile, do you think I can get same `sin/cos/tan` calculation precision as approximate using derivative if I try to implement `CORDIC`?

Answer (score 0):

In microcontrollers especially, the division y/x can often be optimized either by log & exp tables, or with iterative multiplications, until the denominator 1 +- eps = 1 +- x^(2^n) is zero.

```
y/X = y / (1-x) 
    = (1+x)y / (1+x)(1-x)
    = (1+x)(1+x^2)y / (1-x^2)(1+x^2)
    = (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)y / (1-x^4)(1+x^4)
```